# Rails 3 No Method Error undefined method 'current_page'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, kaminari

`Rails -v 3.2.3`
im using `kaminari` to do pagination but i keep getting a **NO METHOD ERROR**, `undefined method 'current_page' for nil:NilClass`

in  **views/layouts/application.html.erb** where line #7 raised:

`<%= paginate @links, :remote => true %>`

is this happening because i have it on the application view instead of my link submission view? does it matter where you place the paginate link?

in /controllers/links_controllers.rb (in a method called submissions)

`@links = Link.page(params[:page]).per(20)`

Comment: I think this is telling you that `@links` is a nil object, are you setting it to something in your controller?

Comment: yep in the controller i have it set to `@links = Link.page(params[:page]).per(20)`

Comment: errr sorry this is happening in `app/controllers/links_controller.rb:29:in 'new'`  where i have `@link = Link.new `

Comment: i'd remove the `:remote` part for now to simplify things, and maybe output to the logger to make sure @links is set - `logger.debug @links`, `logger.debug @links.length`

Comment: ok - guessing you don't want pagination on your new view? so remove it and put it on your index view

Comment: It does matter where you place this link: <%= paginate @links, :remote => true %> - it will need to go in the relevant view (one of the links views I guess since you're defining your links variable in the links controller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out... basically I had to move my `<%= paginate @links %>` code to my **submissions.html.erb** page (which is a part of my links views) I then ran `bundle` to make sure `will_paginate` was gone from my gemsfile and voilà, it worked.

Comment: Great you came back here to answer your own question! Please accept your answer to, so that everybody knows your problem was solved.